# Android: How to fetch or get specific image from any URl or LINK as like facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, url

i have to use image from any url as like facebook does. But i can't understood to how it possible in android. and how can i migrate in my application. i show one iOS question and answer that uses facebook graph api for get information from url, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851482/get-a-specific-image-from-any-url-like-facebook-does) link for facebook graph API, so please help me for this question solution.

see below image i want like that in android
[image]

Comment: where do you want to display image

Comment: in custom listview with image and text

Comment: use picasso lib. here is the link http://square.github.io/picasso/ . this will display images from url and also handle error by itself.

Comment: @SameerDonga picaso library use for only link base image not get image from any link like i will use www.google.com, www.facebook.com, that link from get to image of perticuller link.

Comment: see my question update with image..

Comment: @RaviVGHL Make a custom Adapter and a getter setter class for showing the images in your listview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I got answer after long research. That for i have to use [JSOUP.jar](http://jsoup.org/) file and impliment in my project. that can be parse in HTML and we can use to detail from html,
Now i want image, title and description so i will get from HTML.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Document document;
String url ;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
TextView t1, t2;
ImageView img;
String title, desc, img_url;
Button btn;
EditText et;
Bitmap bitmap;
String UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            url = et.getText().toString();
            new FetchWebsiteData().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String websiteTitle, websiteDescription, imgurl;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to website
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(UserAgent).get();
            // Get the html document title
            websiteTitle = document.title();
            Elements description = document.select("meta[name=description]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            websiteDescription = description.attr("content");
            String ogImage = null;
            Elements metaOgImage = document.select("meta[property=og:image]");
            if (metaOgImage != null) {
                imgurl = metaOgImage.first().attr("content");
                System.out.println("src :<<<------>>> " + ogImage);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        t1.setText(websiteTitle + "------" + imgurl);
        t2.setText(websiteDescription);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imgurl).into(img);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

  }
 }
```

And my XML file for view all data is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.copy.urlparsing.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/asf"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtDesc"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it throws exception every time

Answer (score 0):

This you can get by fetching **favicon** of the website. Google provided one [URL](http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.com), passing domain into query it will fetch image.

The other option is to get it directly from website appending [favicon.ico](https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico) in domain name

*Also as you gave the example of Skype, it is fetching preview of url you pass, not any particular image.*

```
(domain/favicon.ico)
```